# quartz scheduler jobs that execute on all servers in a cluster

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Once I enable clustering in Quartz, it will distribute the cron jobs to the various servers in the cluster. That's fine normally, but there's actually one job that I'd like to have executed on every server in the cluster every time it's scheduled to run.

Is there a way to mark a quartz cron job to indicate that it should run on all servers in a cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by having two quartz schedulers running. One was configured as a clustered scheduler. The other was configured as a local scheduler. Obviously, jobs that are supposed to run on all machines would get added to the local scheduler.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How you were able to establish the link between local and distributed scheduler?